# What is the difference between AND OR operators in the brackets and without?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to better understand how `SQL` reads AND/OR Operators depending on whether I use brackets or not.

For example:

```
Select *
From Table1
Where (C1=ProductA or C1=ProductB) AND C3>20150101

Select *
From Table1
Where C1=ProductA or C1=ProductB AND C3>20150101
```

In the first example the query will be read correctly - I will only select Product A and B from all products with a release date higher than 1st of January,2015.
However,in the second query I will have 20 extra records where release date would be before 2015,meaning that the third condition is not evaluated if any of the first conditions are correct. Am I understanding it right?

If this is the case I should ALWAYS use brackets around my OR statements when combined with AND, correct?

Thanks in advance.

Most links I found explained the use or and or operators, but did not elaborate on how they can be used when combined.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-and-or-clauses.htm
http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/and_or.php

Comment: Yes, it's better to enclose them in parentheses to prevent that an `OR` mistakenly dupes your `WHERE`.

Answer (score 3):

The point is to always make it obvious what you mean. When you say

```
(A or B) and C
```

It's immediately obvious that you want something that's C, plus (non-exclusively) either A or B.

When you say

```
A or B and C
```

It's not clear whether you're saying `(A or B) and C`, or `A or (B and C)`.

In general, it's a good idea to maintain a *hierarchy* - it's fine to omit parentheses when you're dealing with the same level, e.g.:

```
A and B and C
```

But it's very confusing when they're not, e.g.:

```
A or B and C or D
```

Even if  you understand the operator precedence well, the *intent* is not clear. In a simple example like this, any human would assume you mean `(A or B) and (C or D)`, but SQL instead treats it as `A or (B and C) or D`.

In T-SQL, `and` has [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) over `or`. So your expression turns out to be `A or (B and C)` - obviously not what you wanted. Just use parentheses whenever you're combining different levels (treat the `A or B` as a separate expression), and you'll avoid a lot of trouble.

Don't think about operator precedence. Think about *intent* - that will make it obvious where parentheses make sense, and as a side-effect, work properly :)